# URIError: failed to decode param "/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Please help fix I ran into this error after deploying my webpage to git-pages,

now after running my React app it compiles successfully but does not display anything in the browser when you refresh the page this error pops up on the console.

[link to the React app](https://github.com/Yagi91/Random-Quote-Generator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps given on this repo - [Deploy React to GithubPages](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages)

Alternative - React Deployment pages also explains how you can deploy to github pages [Create-react-app deploy to githubpages](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages)